# Get sqlstate from stored procedure in BTEQ

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I need to know if is possible capturing SQLSTATE from an execution of Stored Procedure in a .BTEQ file for later use, All of this in Teradata.

Comment: Have you tried setting it as an output parameter in your condition handler? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Define your procedure as

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE user.procedure (IN in_parameter INTEGER , OUT sql_state VARCHAR(30))
```

then

```
SET sql_state = SQLSTATE
```

This will get you the sql_state in standard output (Terminal) . you can modify the same for file output .

Comment: I have my procedure defined this way but how i get the output value in a .bteq file?, in my .bteq file I have defined just call to my procedure but not find how i get this parameter

Comment: `.export report file filename.txt` place the code after this line . to reset use `.export reset`